# base class pointer pointing to normal and virtual function

Tags: c++, pointers, inheritance

why does base class pointer pointing to derived class object still points to base class function, if the functions are not declared as virtual

```
class Base
{
public:
    void draw() { cout << "base" << endl; }
    virtual void fun() { cout << "base class function" << endl; }
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    void draw() { cout << "derived" << endl; }
    void fun() { cout << "derived function" << endl; }
};

int main()
{
    Derived d;
    d.draw();  //derived
    Base *b = &d;
    b->draw(); //base
    b->fun();  //derived function
    return 0;
}
```

`b` is a pointer pointing to derived object even then why does `b->draw()` gives output as "base" but not "derived" ?

Comment: Some indentation and spacing would be nice.

Comment: As for the problem, is there a reason why haven't you made the `draw` function `virtual`?

Comment: Question lacks any research, even reading a tutorial

Comment: b is a base class pointer to begin with, it always points to the base class functions. This can be overriden by dynamic parallelism using virtual funcions.

Answer (score 1):

The function will have to be `virtual` to be overridden. That's what `virtual` means: that it can be overloaded.

Answer (score 1):

In C++, non-virtual class functions and class variables (i.e. instance variables or fields) are called by class of pointer, not class of object. Java methods are virtual by default

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the virtual keyword is to decide whether re-definition of a function in a derived class means:

- virtual: actual redefinition of the existing function interface
- non-virtual: just another unrelated member function with the same signature

In the second case, the actual function you call with:

```
d.draw();
b->draw();
```

are defined by the compile-time type of the object you call it on, i.e. a Base instance will call Base::draw, whereas a Derived instance will call Derived::draw. Note that you can also statically call the base-defined method with the same name using:

```
d.Base::draw();
```